# MLT XML: specifying codec for input data

Tags: mlt

I'd like to change the codec ffmpeg inside MLT is using to decode the producer file from native `opus` to `libopus`.

The FFmpeg command should be like: `ffmpeg -acodec libopus -i 851515232352539900.mkv...`.

How can I specify that codec via MLT XML? Using `acodec` doesn't seem to work:

```
<producer id="producer1">
    <property name="resource">test.mp4</property>
    <property name="aspect_ratio">1</property>
    <property name="mlt_service">avformat</property>
    <property name="acodec">libopus</property>
  </producer>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not mention your MLT version. But if it is recent enough, you should be able to use "acodec" to specify a codec to use:

https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/blob/master/src/modules/avformat/producer_avformat.c#L2852

consider running

```
melt -query audio_codecs
```

to see if MLT is aware of libopus

Comment: Thanks Brian! Indeed `acodec` works fine, but `libopus` is not listed in audio_codecs so it was probably ignored. Is there a way to add libopus to the MLT? It seems to be performing much better than native opus codec.

Comment: If libopus is supported by the installation of avcodec that MLT is linked against, then it will show up automatically. MLT itself does not require special installation instructions to use libopus through avcoded.